# AMP4EMAIL: Setting Form Values from State in Templates

Tags: amp-html, amp-bind, amp-email, amp-mustache, amp-form

I'm seemingly unable to dynamically set a a form input field's value via the [value] attribute while using `amp-bind` within an `amp-mustache` template. This issue only occurs in the Gmail client. It works as expected within the Gmail Amp Playground and within the browser. This issue **only** occurs in the Gmail client. It works as expected within the [Gmail Amp Playground](https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/) (which I would assume should mirror the behavior of the Gmail client) and within the browser.

A gist is available [here](https://gist.github.com/avcohen/381d86374215a55d527a97f931ce973c) with a contrived version of the client side code.

Any suggestions / workarounds gratefully appreciated!

And while it's likely not needed, here's the server-side logic:

```cs
        public class TestRequestModel {
            public string TestId { get; set; }
        }
        private string ValidId = "correct";
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TestGetId([FromForm]AEGetRepresentativesRequestModel requestModel)
        {
            AddRequiredAmpHeaders();
            if (requestModel == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new {});
            }
            return Ok(new TestRequestModel { TestId = ValidId });
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TestUseId([FromForm]TestRequestModel requestModel)
        {
            AddRequiredAmpHeaders();
            if (requestModel == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new {});
            }
            if (requestModel.TestId != ValidId)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { Error = $"Invaild id: {requestModel.TestId}" });
            }
            return Ok(new { TestId = ValidId });
        }
```

Comment: There's currently a bug in Gmail that's interfering with how `event.response` works with forms. This should be fixed very soon.

Comment: @fstanis - Thanks for the reply. Are you able to provide any links to where this might be documented?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** seems there's a [second bug in Gmail](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/25920#issuecomment-565852958) that's still affecting this.

This was caused by a bug in Gmail that interfered with how `event.response` worked when it was used in combination with `AMP.setState`. I just checked and it seems to be fixed now, so your code should work.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. I just tried the same code again and while it still does work in the gmail playground it there's no change in the gmail client. Is there anywhere public this bug is being tracked?